# Efficient RegEx to Force Single Space After CSS Attribute Value

Tags: css, regex, dreamweaver

As I often work in Dreamweaver for basic CSS work ... DW code completion tends to add CSS attribute values directly after the colon without spacing ... {attr:value}. As this has caused some real debugging headaches due to rendering issues with picky browsers, I often find myself having to manually add the space after the colon. [^D.R.Y.]

I'm currently working on building a simple regex snippet that I can run to format the CSS properly ...

What I currently have seems to work but I think it's a bit crude ... I'm basically just trying  to see if there are any suggestions ... Here's what I've got ...

```
(.*?(?={).*?:)([^\s][\w!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]*.*?;})
```

And Replacing the line with ...

```
 \s$2
```

► Clarification ► Below I've Somewhat Improved the Solution Above ... I Still Think It Needs Refinement Though ...

```
(?:(?={*))(?:\s*?)([\s\r\n]*?\b[\w!#$%&'*+/=?^_`|~-]*:(?!.*{))(?!\s)(.*?;)
```

And Replacing With ...

```
$1 $2
```

► Perl Version ►

Perl makes very light work of this ...

```
perl -pi -e 's/^(.*?:)([^\s].*?;).*$/$1 $2/ig'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you run your regex snippet in a C# program, I have the solution for you:

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?<=\{{1}[\s\r\n]*)((?<Attribute>[^}:\n\r\s]+):\s+(?<Value>[^;]*);[\s\r\n]*)*(?=\})");

regex.Replace(input, match =>
{
    var replacement = string.Empty;
    for (var i = 0; i < match.Groups["Attribute"].Captures.Count; i++)
    {
        replacement += string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}: {1}\r\n", match.Groups["Attibute"].Captures[i], match.Groups["Value"].Captures[i]);
    }
    return replacement;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work (JavaScript)

```js
'{attr:value}'.replace(/({.*?:)\s*/g,'$1 ')
```

This gives `'{attr: value}'` as the output.

Comment: Thanks Narenda ... However This will fail if the attributes aren't on the same line?  The portion below won't match where there are indeterminate lines ... 

    {.*?: 

Moreover, I need to use this as a snippet - as search and replace utility per se so JS wouldn't be too effective here ... Thanks for your help though :-)