# Dreamweaver CS6 format source code CSS adds space after :

Tags: css, format, dreamweaver

When applying source formatting in Dreamweaver CS6, it adds a space after the colons in CSS files.  Is there any way to change this and other formatting behaviors not found in the "CSS Source Format Options" dialog?  Is there an extension that might help?

Example:

```
.someSelector { color:#abc123; }
```

becomes

```
.someSelector { color: #abc123; }
```

Note the space after `color:`.

Comment: Either syntax works. Is there a specific reason you do not want the space after the colon?

Comment: OCD, readability, less code, and differences with repository versions.

Answer (score 1):

In Dreamweaver 5.5 you **can't** make the change you want. [Format CSS Code from Adobe Online Help](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WS6A10E93F-6587-4e1b-956C-03CBD7F678BBa.html) (Which is out because Funkyscript said he'd already seen it.)

The nearest thing I could find was a file at **C:\Program Files(x86)\Adobe\Adobe Dreamweaver CS5.5\configuration\TagLibraries\CSS\properties.xml**. This lists the valid options for CSS, but again, nothing about whitespace.

You'll probably have to use a regular expression to get what you want. Update: Just found this RegEx question, which is the reverse of what you want: [Efficient RegEx to Force Single Space After CSS Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788319/efficient-regex-to-force-single-space-after-css-attribute-value?rq=1)

That said, I think having the space after the colon enhances readability. Maybe your diff tool can exclude whitespace changes?